# Pandas replace all numeric values not equal to a specific value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My DataFrame:

```
            HLLM  HXBX  JHWO  RPNZ  ZHNL
2008-08-31     0     0     0     0     0
2008-09-30     0     0     0     0     0
2008-10-31     3     1     0     0     5
2008-11-30     0    -1     0     0     0
```

I am trying to replace all values that are NOT equal to 0 to the value 1

```
df = df.replace(df != 0, 1)
```

How can I rewrite this so that it works?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply use

```
df[df != 0] = 1        

HLLM  HXBX  JHWO  RPNZ  ZHNL
2008-08-31     0     0     0     0     0
2008-09-30     0     0     0     0     0
2008-10-31     1     1     0     0     1
2008-11-30     0     1     0     0     0
```

Answer (score 4):

For the zero case, you can use the fact non-zero values are considered "Truthy":

```
df = df.astype(bool).astype(int)
```

For the general case, you can use [`pd.DataFrame.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
df.mask(df.ne(0), 1, inplace=True)

print(df)

            HLLM  HXBX  JHWO  RPNZ  ZHNL
2008-08-31     0     0     0     0     0
2008-09-30     0     0     0     0     0
2008-10-31     1     1     0     0     1
2008-11-30     0     1     0     0     0
```